# Conversão shapefile para raster usando Python e biblioteca GDAL

Tags: python

Estou fazendo a conversão de um arquivo *shapefile* para *raster*, utilizando um script Python e a biblioteca GDAL.

Para isto utilizo duas funções:

1. A função `gdal.rasterizeOptions` (coloco as opções de saída do meu dado em raster).
2. Função `gdal.Rasterize` (função que vai *rasterizar* o meu *shapefile* efetivamente).

Entretanto, meu código não roda. Alguém sabe se estou passando os parâmetros da função errada?

```
from osgeo 
import gdal
from osgeo import ogr


dado_saida = 'C:\Lilian\_fabio\criando-aplicacao-conversao\python\pre\saida.tif'

dado_entrada = 'C:\Lilian\_fabio\criando-aplicacao-conversao\python\pre\grid_pontos_1.shp'

data = ogr.Open(dado_entrada)

rasterizeOptions=gdal.RasterizeOptions(options=[], format='Gtiff',creationOptions = None, noData=None,initValues = None, outputBounds = None, outputSRS = None,width = None, height = None, xRes= 1, yRes= 1, targetAlignedPixels = False,bands = None, inverse = False, allTouched=True,burnValues = None, attribute='Z', useZ = False, layers = None,SQLStatement='select Z, * from saida',SQLDialect = None, where = None, callback=None, callback_data=None)

gdal.Rasterize(dado_entrada, dado_saida, options=rasterizeOptions)
```

Comment: detalhe importante: evite usar `\ ` para separar diretórios, mesmo no windows - por que várias combinações de `\ ` mais um carácter podem gerar um carácter comletamente diferente. Por exemplo `\n` internamente se torna um único carácter com código 16 em decimal.

Comment: (em Python você pode usar normalmente o `/` para separar diretórios, mesmo estando no windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lilian,

modifiquei seu código junto a um amigo meu e conseguimos fazer com que ele compile e gere um .tif. Verifique se é o que você quer e se a saída é condizente com o esperado.

```
import ogr, gdal

dado_entrada = '/home/caiquefortunato/GDAL/cavas-juntas/saida.tif'

dado_saida = '/home/caiquefortunato/GDAL/cavas-juntas/grid_pontos_1.shp'

rasterizeOptions = gdal.RasterizeOptions(options=[], format='Gtiff',creationOptions = None, noData=None,initValues = None, outputBounds = None, outputSRS = None,width = None, height = None, xRes= 1, yRes= 1, targetAlignedPixels = False,bands = None, inverse = False, allTouched=True,burnValues = None, attribute='field_4', useZ = False, layers = None,SQLStatement='select field_4, * from grid_pontos_1',SQLDialect = None, where = None, callback=None, callback_data=None)

gdal.Rasterize(dado_entrada, dado_saida, options=rasterizeOptions)
```

O erro era que na função Rasterize primeiro vem a saida e depois a entrada. Para economizar tempo só renomeei as variáveis.

Espero ter ajudado. Tenha um feliz natal, com muitas luzes.

Comment: Vocês são as melhores pessoas que o o Papai Noel vai presentear com muitos muitos muitos presentes esses ano hehe <3 <3